# Bluetooth speakers lag

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bluetooth, lag

There seems to be a 200ms lag on sound when I use my blue-tooth speakers (1/2 meter distance) in windows 7 (belkin 6.0.1 vista drivers.). Is there a way to reduce this?

Answer (score 3):

Some video players like VLC can compensate for the Bluetooth lag by advancing the audio ahead of the video. In VLC if you press "J" while the video is playing you can adjust the audio "delay" to -250ms. There's a [preference](http://lifehacker.com/367558/fix-desynchronized-video-and-audio-with-vlc) to set this permanently.

Comment: media player classic also, and the newer MPC home theatre version both with ability to do what David noted. In those you might have to turn on the built in audio switcher option I set the Hotkey to Ctrl+-

Comment: My problem was with audio lag while playing a game, but it is very useful to know that you can overcome this in a different situation.

Comment: then your screwed :-)  (something like) buffers  on both sides of bluetooth, for keeping that data rate pouring good, Not the time it takes to pass the radiowaves over the air , are what seems to add in the delay. Nowdays there are buffers and processing of data occuring all over the place.  Any compression of the data also would take time.  They could do this same basic things, in way less ms, because they do it for pro wireless mics stuff. but when it comes to bluetooth  everyone who Analised the reality, knows that the delay is huge.  A game cant predict that your going to fire.

Comment: yep pretty much! I use wires now :(

Comment: @Psycogeek: well you could delay the video then! Although in most videogames that would be just as bad... :(